# syntax highlighting in vs code changed after "Workspace Trust" warning

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fonts

I originally wrote this

```
Import tkinter
```

> the color of 'tkinter' is green, but after warning 'Workspace Trust' everything changes to flat white

Comment: Your theme dictates the color of the syntax in VSCode's editor. Look for a theme in VSCode that appeals to you, and fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to switch the theme of the VSCode?

[image]